# How to calculate position for div with absolute when browser window change width

Tags: javascript

I have img and div under it with position absolute. So I need that this div always start from bottom right corner of image and go to left. But div gets off from img bottom corner after resize browser window when I use this code :

```
div1.style.left = ((imgRect.left + 
  (window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft) - 
  (document.body.clientLeft || 0)) 
  - 532) + "px";
```

Note that div take correct position when refresh the page, but how to do this without refreshing?

I try to add this code:

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
  div1.style.left = ((imgRect.left + 
    (window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft) - 
    (document.body.clientLeft || 0)) 
    - 532) + "px";
});
```

but still have same result. I guess it is not a correct calculation.

Comment: I am having trouble trying to follow what you are trying to accomplish. Could you post a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty wrong with your code, but the bit that's causing your code not to work is the `div1` variable is likely inaccessible within the resize callback. Ensure `div1` is available within the function and you should be good to go.